# Why is the code displaying in this while loop? Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm having issues understading while loops. I just started learning Python and I don't understand why this code still runs even though the conditional is False. It doesn't keep looping, but it keeps displaying the code when I select the Exit option. Then it doesn't display it again but if I select Exit I don't want the code displaying. How can I do that?

```
def nether_coords (x,y,z):
    x = x/8
    y = y/8
    z = z/8
    
    print (f" X: {x}\n Y: {y}\n Z: {z}")
    return x, y, z

menu = 0
while menu != 2:
    print (" [1] start\n [2] exit")
    menu = int (input ("Select an Option: ")) 
    
    x = int (input("Input X:\n"))
    y = int (input("Input Y:\n"))
    z = int (input("Input X:\n"))

    nether_coords (x,y,z)
    print (nether_coords)
```

Yes, it's Minecraft related, so it's very important :)

Comment: You still do the calculations and print the result after you have asked for `menu`; only after those calculations are done is the `while` condition being checked again.

Comment: you probably want that input question once before you go into the loop, and then at the very bottom every time thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def nether_coords (x,y,z):
    x = x/8
    y = y/8
    z = z/8
    
    print (f" X: {x}\n Y: {y}\n Z: {z}")
    return x, y, z

menu = 0
print (" [1] start\n [2] exit")
menu = int (input ("Select an Option: ")) 
while menu != 2:

    
    x = int (input("Input X:\n"))
    y = int (input("Input Y:\n"))
    z = int (input("Input X:\n"))

    nether_coords (x,y,z)
    print (nether_coords)

    print (" [1] start\n [2] exit")
    menu = int (input ("Select an Option: "))
```

I think you mean this, you must get option before while check first.

Then input 3 numbers and do nether_coords.

After that ask for option for while check again.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will perform all the inputs after the menu variable gets assigned to 2 and will check the value of menu only at the next iteration.
Here's a quick fix:

```
def nether_coords (x,y,z):
    x = x/8
    y = y/8
    z = z/8

    print (f" X: {x}\n Y: {y}\n Z: {z}")
    return x, y, z

menu = 0
while menu != 2:
  print (" [1] start\n [2] exit")
  menu = int (input ("Select an Option: ")) 
  if menu == 2:
    print("Exiting")
    break
  x = int (input("Input X:\n"))
  y = int (input("Input Y:\n"))
  z = int (input("Input X:\n"))

  nether_coords (x,y,z)
  print (nether_coords)
```

You also have a potential bug at the bottom where you are calling your print statement. Remove the second to last function call. It should instead read something like:
`print(nether_coords(x,y,z))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def nether_coords (x,y,z):
    x = x/8
    y = y/8
    z = z/8

    print (f" X: {x}\n Y: {y}\n Z: {z}")
    return x, y, z

menu = 0
while menu != 2:
  print (" [1] start\n [2] exit")
  menu = int (input ("Select an Option: ")) 
  if menu == 2:
    print("Exiting")
    break
  x = int (input("Input X:\n"))
  y = int (input("Input Y:\n"))
  z = int (input("Input X:\n"))

  nether_coords (x,y,z)
```

You have to `break` the while loop after getting input 2 in menu. You don't need `return x, y, z` in `nether_coords` function if you just want to display coordinates (because you have print statement in function). Also  `print(nether_coords)` will display function's memory location which you don't really want.